# Window Tempering Rules and Interior Doors

Tags: code-compliance

Are interior doors included in the discussion of the 24/60 rule?  In other words, if I have a pane of glass that is within 24 inches of an interior door, does that mean it must be tempered?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you please finish your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is basically to use tempered glass if someone can fall through it. I don't see any distinction made between exterior and interior doors, nor would I expect to, because exterior vs interior doors do not change this risk.

"Glazing in an individual fixed or operable panel adjacent to a door where the nearest vertical edge of the glazing is within a 24-inch (610 mm) arc of either vertical edge of the door in a closed position and where the bottom exposed edge of the glazing is less than 60 inches (1524 mm) above the walking surface shall be considered a hazardous location." (California code, but I don't think it matters here.)
https://up.codes/viewer/california/ca-building-code-2016-v2/chapter/24/glass-and-glazing#2406.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Tempered glass is Not required if the bottom edge of the window is 1) more than 18” above the floor, 2) not within 24” of a door, 3) top edge is less than 36” above the floor, 4) glass in closet doors not more than 3” wide, 5) walking surface is not within 36” of glass below 60” above walking surface. (See ICC R308)

Btw, There are only two items in the Code that are NOT grandfathered in compliance AND must be corrected as soon as discovered: 1) smoke detectors, and 2) tempered glazing.